# How to play sound on phone call with Android?

Tags: android, audio, phone-call

It is possible to programmatically interact with a phone call?  Can you, for example, play audio to a caller from a program?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  You need to go through your previous questions and mark the best answer as the correct one by clicking the checkbox next to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google has not exposed any API which allows us to feed data to a particular ongoing call. You can however have control over a call. Check this article : [here](http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.com/2010/09/call-control-in-android.html)